# Oracle - Add days/months to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE field

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to dynamically add some days (or months) to an existing TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE field.

```
select DATED from MY_TABLE where ID = 1165;
```

gives:

```
DATED
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
20-FEB-16 04.31.54 AM EUROPE/MOSCOW
```

when I run:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATED = DATED + 2 WHERE ID = 1165;
```

it gives:

```
DATED
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
22-FEB-16 04.31.54 AM +03:00
```

So how to properly add 2 days and not to loose timestamp "EUROPE/MOSCOW"

How to add 2 months the same way as days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `DATED = DATED + 2`, then DATED is implicitly converted to a `DATE` value (which does not have any time zone information) and then converted back to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value using your current session time zone settings.

Try

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATED = DATED + INTERVAL '2' DAY WHERE ID = 1165;
```

or

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATED = DATED + 2 * INTERVAL '1' DAY WHERE ID = 1165;
```

or

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATED = DATED + NUMTODSINTERVAL(2, 'day') WHERE ID = 1165;
```

In order to add 2 months you can use

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DATED = DATED + INTERVAL '2' MONTH WHERE ID = 1165;
```

resp. `NUMTOYMINTERVAL(2, 'MONTH')`, for example.

Comment: + INTERVAL '2' DAY gives an error ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>

Comment: NUMTODSINTERVAL(2, 'day') works but MONTH argument is not applicable to NUMTODSINTERVAL function (only day, hour, minute, second) ..

Comment: That's why I also wrote `NUMTOYMINTERVAL(2, 'MONTH')`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wemfried !

Comment: @Alexander - you need to be aware that adding an interval of two months can fail, if the new date isn't valid; e.g. adding two months to 31-Jul errors because there is no 31-Sep. Add using add_months instead would lose the time zone info again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `INTERVAL` to add months is that it will throw errors if there are not enough days in the resulting month:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-01-30 00:00:00.000' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
         + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
FROM DUAL;
```

Gives:

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

However, you can write a simple(ish) function to do the arithmetic:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TS_ADD_MONTHS(
  datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  months   INT
) RETURN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_tz   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := EXTRACT( TIMEZONE_REGION FROM datetime );
  p_date CONSTANT DATE         := TRUNC( datetime, 'MI' );
  
  INVALID_TZ_DST EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_TZ_DST, -1878);
BEGIN
  RETURN FROM_TZ(CAST(ADD_MONTHS(p_date, months) AS TIMESTAMP), p_tz)
         + (datetime - FROM_TZ(CAST(p_date AS TIMESTAMP), p_tz));
EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_TZ_DST THEN
    -- Handle invalid timestamp between daylight savings time changes by adding
    -- 1 hour.
    RETURN FROM_TZ(
             CAST(ADD_MONTHS(p_date + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, months) AS TIMESTAMP),
             p_tz
           )
           + (datetime - FROM_TZ(CAST(p_date AS TIMESTAMP), p_tz));
    
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```sql
With test_data (dt, months) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-01-30 12:12:12.012 EST5EDT', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-02-14 02:05:05.012 EST5EDT', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-10-07 02:34:56.789 EST5EDT', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-01-28 01:05:05.012 Europe/London', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-08-31 01:34:56.789 Europe/London', 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT TS_ADD_MONTHS(dt, months) AS datetime
FROM test_data;
```

**Output**:

> | DATETIME |
> | --- |
> | 2016-02-29 12:12:12.012000000 EST5EDT |
> | 2021-03-14 03:05:05.012000000 EST5EDT |
> | 2021-11-07 02:34:56.789000000 EST5EDT |
> | 2021-03-28 02:05:05.012000000 EUROPE/LONDON |
> | 2021-10-31 01:34:56.789000000 EUROPE/LONDON |

*Note: this has shifted the time by 1 hour when the new timestamp would fall between the spring change for daylight savings time and would otherwise result in an invalid date.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2963f5fc42bf471e332b50de3540ad60)*

Comment: @AlexPoole Updated and also made `DETERMINISTIC`